# Ubuntu says not enough free disk space running on Hyper-V Vm

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a Hyper-V Virtual Machine. The problem I face is that Ubuntu constantly says that I don't have enough disk space (says there's 12.3GB total) but on Hyper-V, when I inspect the Virtual Hard Disk, it says the maximum disk size is 16GB (I increased it a bit).

[Ubuntu disk space information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74lUx.png)

[Hyper-V Virtual Hard Disk current & maximum disk size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqMiL.png)

I guess that I'm comparing 2 different things because the current file size in Hyper-V is different than what I see on Ubuntu.

Comment: Expanding the capacity of the virtual disk doesn't necessarily expand the partition from the guest OS's perspective.

Comment: @squillman That's what I thought, so how can I increase the partition capacity?

Comment: Have a look at this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196512/how-to-extend-filesystem-partition-on-ubuntu-vm

Answer (score 2):

Your `16GB` in Hyper-V is the space size of VM Ubuntu, and `12.3GB` is the space size of VM Ubuntu's disk.

Though you can set the auto-enlarged disk for the VM Ubuntu, the maximum size of auto-enlarged disk for Ubuntu/Debian is `12GB`, no matter where you set, in Hyper-V, or even in VirtualBox.

SO, you need to enlarge the space size of two of them, yes, both of them, the space size of VM Ubuntu and the space size of VM Ubuntu's disk.

Notice: if the usage percent of disk space is over 80, that is 80% used disk space, that disk is in dangerous staus.

1.Please change `16GB` into `32GB` or even `40GB` in your host Hyper-V, this is to change your VM space size. This changed space is virtual space, not the physical space. I just set `32GB` for an example.

2.Please use partition tools to enlarge your VM's disk space size `12.3GB`.

Just use `df -hT` to check the usage of your VM's disk in your VM's terminal(or please login your VM), output just liking below:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  465M     0  465M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      98M  2.4M   96M   3% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4       11G   11G     0 100% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     489M     0  489M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs      98M   60K   98M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Please use `sudo cfdisk` to check your VM's disk on your VM terminal, I guess your output just liking below:

```
Device     Boot    Start      End    Sectors      Size    Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 23164927   25162880  12.8125G    83 Linux
/dev/sda1x      23164928 23384880    4299680   2.6709G     c W95 FAT32(LBA)
free space      23384881 25384880    1096800  528.998M
```

First, you should use `fdisk` or `cfdisk` or `parted`to move your second partition`/dev/sda1X`

(I can not see first photo all) which mounted in `/boot/efi` to the end cylinder of your VM's disk.

Second, Using `cfdisk` to resize or extend or enlarge your first partition `/dev/sda1`, may be the default size of resized `/dev/sda1` operated by `cfdisk` is `28GB`;

Third, do not forget set all the file types of partition `/dev/sda1` into `ext4` via `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`.

Fourth, restart or reboot your virtual machine, and have fun!

OVER!